# Complicated formatting of a string list

Tags: string-manipulation

I have the following list:

```
l={"ALMONDBEAN", "ALMONDMILK", "ALMONDOLIVE_OIL", "ALMONDORANGE_PEEL", 
"ALMONDVANILLA", "ALMONDWHEAT", "ALMONDWHISKEY", "ANISECUCUMBER",
"ANISELEMON", "APPLEAPPLE_BRANDY", "APPLEBLACK_CURRANT",
"APPLECHERRY", "AVOCADOMILK"}
```

I want to modify it to have the following:

```
l={"Food.ALMOND.ALMONDBEAN", "Food.ALMOND.ALMONDMILK", "Food.ALMOND.ALMONDOLIVE_OIL", "Food.ALMOND.ALMONDORANGE_PEEL", 
    "Food.ALMOND.ALMONDVANILLA", "Food.ALMOND.ALMONDWHEAT", "Food.ALMOND.ALMONDWHISKEY", "Food.ANISE.ANISECUCUMBER",
    "Food.ANISE.ANISELEMON", "Food.APPLE.APPLEAPPLE_BRANDY", "Food.APPLE.APPLEBLACK_CURRANT",
    "Food.AVOCADO.APPLECHERRY", "Food.AVOCADO.AVOCADOMILK"}
```

Two things happen in this process: 
1. "Food." shall be added to the beginning of each entry,
2. The first word of each entry shall be added to the middle. For example when we have `"ALMONDBEAN"` we want to get `"ALMOND."` and eventually have `"Food.ALMOND.ALMONDBEAN"`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
ClearAll[reArrange]
reArrange[s_String] := ## & @@ StringCases[s, 
   StartOfString ~~ w__ ~~ rest__ ~~ EndOfString /; 
     (And @@ DictionaryWordQ /@ {w, ## & @@ StringSplit[rest, "_"]}) :> 
       StringRiffle[{"Food", w, s}, "."]]

reArrange /@ l
```

> {"Food.ALMOND.ALMONDBEAN", "Food.ALMOND.ALMONDMILK", 
>   "Food.ALMOND.ALMONDOLIVE_OIL", "Food.ALMOND.ALMONDORANGE_PEEL", 
>   "Food.ALMOND.ALMONDVANILLA", "Food.ALMOND.ALMONDWHEAT", 
>   "Food.ALMOND.ALMONDWHISKEY", "Food.ANISE.ANISECUCUMBER", 
>   "Food.ANISE.ANISELEMON", "Food.APPLE.APPLEAPPLE_BRANDY", 
>   "Food.APPLE.APPLEBLACK_CURRANT", "Food.APPLE.APPLECHERRY", 
>   "Food.AVOCADO.AVOCADOMILK"}