# Modification to the list of string

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation

Suppose we have a list of the following:

```
l={"applejuice","lemon_juiceginger"}
```

How can one modifies this to read as:

```
{"apple:juice","lemon_juice:ginger"}
```

I have tried `StringRiffle[]` but wasn't so successful.

Comment: How do you determine where to insert the `:`?  The example is not self-explanatory.

Comment: after each known word, apple is known so as juice. problem is with enteries like `lemon_juice` where there is "_".

Comment: Assuming you need to detect and split words, have you tried any techniques from answers to your recent question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/189303/5478?

Comment: @William what kind of problem because "after each known word" means that `"lemon_juiceginger"` should be `"lemon:_juice:ginger:"`.

Comment: @Kuba I have tried the method I asked in previous post. The "_" is the reason I am asking this here. Let me be specific. the ":" should go after the first known word. One expects "apple:juice" which is fine. Yet when there is "lemon_juiceginger" you get "lemon:_juiceginger" how would one sort the string such that it understand lemon_juice is one word?

Comment: @William why is "lemon_juice" one word and "apple juice" isn't?

Comment: I have this problem because I have data from different databases gathered together. I just made an nominal example. This issue is "_"

Comment: Whatever you need, just update the question with a clear description of rules and a set of test examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a slight modification of the function `reArrange` from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/189318/125):

```
ClearAll[reArrange2]
reArrange2[s_String] := ## & @@ 
  StringCases[s, StartOfString ~~ beg__ ~~ w__ ~~ EndOfString /; 
    (And @@ DictionaryWordQ /@ {w, ## & @@ StringSplit[beg, "_"]}) :> 
     StringRiffle[{beg, w}, ":"]]

reArrange2 /@ l
```

> {"apple:juice", "lemon_juice:ginger"}